# Why does Rust f32 does not give good solution but f64 does?

Tags: rust, floating-point, precision

This simple program compiles without any issue and equality assertion is evaluated as true.

```
fn main() {
    let celsius_temp: f64 = 23.0;
    let fahrenheit_temp: f64 = celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius_temp);

    assert_eq!(fahrenheit_temp, 73.4);
    println!("Test passed!");
}

fn celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius_temp: f64) -> f64 {
    (celsius_temp * 1.8) + 32.0
}
```

However, if I use instead of f64 a data type of f32, Rust compiler panics and assertion is false. It gives me a following message: thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
left: `73.399994`,
right: `73.4`'

Why does it work with f64 and not with f32? I am not using here large numbers.

Comment: look clippy warning (actually clippy report your code as error) https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#float_cmp

Comment: Thnx, @Stargateur , this clippy warning explained it!